# Difference in grammar between must and have to

Tags: grammar

Could someone please explain the difference between Must and have to??? it is so complicated to understand the difference... Should i use "must" for obligations and "have to" to give pieces of advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both "must" and "have to" can have the same meaning of requirement or obligation

> You **must** finish your vegetables before you can have dessert.
>   You **have to** finish your vegetables before you can have desert.
>
> You **must** water the plants or else they will die.
>   You **have to** water the plants or else they will die.

though "must" is usually considered to be an intensifier and stronger.
A lot depends on context.

However, the negations have different meanings

> You **must not** open the door.

implies a requirement which needs to be fulfilled.

> You **don't have to** open the door.

implies a request which may or may not be fulfilled.

Comment: *You **must not** open the door = You **have to not** open the door.*